# Alias javascript keywords

Tags: javascript

Can I alias JavaScript keywords? For example, can I set up a shorthand for `function` to be `func`:

```
func add(a, b){
    return a + b;
}
```

or a shortcut to `delete`:

`del a;`

Comment: Why? `tion` putting you over some arbitrary bandwidth cap? Obfuscate, or take CoffeeScript and put a layer on it.

Comment: Why would you want to make JavaScript any less readable?

Comment: (in javascript) if the `function` keyword had to (or could) be changed, i'd go with pico's way where the name of the function is mandatory. example in pico: `add(a,b):a+b` but i'm not sure how this would effect the grammar of javascript. if you want an unnamed function, i'd name them `fn`. [i'd like to see if i could write a pico to javascript translater like pyjamas does for python]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No you cannot. Naming keywords are something you don't have any control over.

Answer (score 0):

That's a very good question. I am all about cutting bytes. Every byte has to be downloaded by the end-user. JavaScript is very readable to people who know how to read it. But the answer is no, and that's a shame.