# Writing Javascript Algorithm, but I need to convert symbols into actual words

Tags: javascript

So, I'm writing a new JavaScript algorithm, codenamed jBam (Javascript Browser Algorithm Module), and it is used to write an extremely simple way to detect a browser and it's version. My main goal, is to be able to write this (with the library plugged in):

```
if(IE & version lessThan 9) {
    // IE code for 8 and below
}
```

Right now, progress is going pretty good. I can write

```
if(browser == IE & version < 9)
```

**So**, back to my original question, the only thing I want to know is maybe someway set a variable for `lessThan` and set it equal to the symbol `<`. I've tried probably the most common remedy (`var lessThan = <`) but, of course, that's a little too wishful, and a little too easy. And, as we all know, nothing is ever *too* easy. Any suggestions, maybe a JavaScript preserve I'm not thinking of?

Comment: Not possible. Why not just use the `<` symbol anyway? It's cleaner and takes less bytes.

Comment: Similar question has already been answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8539027/alias-javascript-keywords

Comment: @SandeepGB That really doesn't have to do with the OP's question. They're really talking about changing/aliasing operators, not reserved keywords...

Comment: Any particular reason why you're using the bitwise operator `&` instead of `&&`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @JCOC611, but it's also possible that you make everything part of an object, and then make `version` an object as a property as well, where you can add a method called `lessThan`, so you would have something like:

```
var browserStuff = {
    browser: {
        value: "",
        is: function (comparator) {
            if (browserStuff.browser.value == comparator) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    },
    version: {
        value: "",
        lessThan: function (comparator) {
            if (browserStuff.version.value < comparator) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    },
    init: function () {
        // Do your stuff to determine the browser and its version
        // You need to set browserStuff.version.value and browserStuff.browser.value
        delete browserStuff.init;
    }
}.init();
```

And then use it like:

```
if (browserStuff.browser.is("IE")) {

}
```

or

```
if (browserStuff.version.lessThan("7")) {

}
```

You'd have to add more things for "greater than" and "not equals" and whatnot, but that's just to start it off.

I don't exactly suggest this, because you can just as easily use normal Javascript operators to accomplish the same thing with less redundant code. This solution is more for a "readable" theme, but is in no way necessary or better.

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys... @JCOC611 I wanted to use lte, lt, gte, gt and equalto, instead of having to use <=, <, >=, >, and ==, cause it's simpler, and I will be writing this "library" (i guess you could call it) for a client. And bfavaretto - I'm using & instead of && because it works and is simpler and takes less. ianpgall Thanks for that, but I've already written a pretty effective algorithm which I seem to like for it's simplicity. Thanks for everyone's input! -decotton

Comment: @user1672778 No problem! Well I guess the short, straightforward answer is that you cannot change `<`, etc. into words or anything else