# JavaScript: is it possible to alias the 'debugger'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, v8, node-inspector

Many JS host environments provide a 'debugger' that invokes an interactive debugger. For example:

- node.js will invoke Node Inpsector
- Chrome will invoke Chrome Dev Tools

I use both of these quite frequently. I was wondering if, in environments that support this, there was a way I could create an alias for the debugger, eg. so:

```
d
```

has the same effect as

```
debugger
```

Is this possible?

Comment: In most cases.. debugger is an object... just let d = debugger and it should point to the same object

Comment: @user1600124 debugger is not an object, your code gives a syntax error: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token debugger`

Comment: hmm... triggers inspector/devtools... not an object then... these are probably not possible to set alias to unless you compile your own host environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`debugger` is a keyword and it's not possible to delegate it's special meaning to a variable (you will find a similar question about aliases [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8539027/alias-javascript-keywords)).

You can wrap `debugger` with a function:

```
d = function() {
   debugger;
};
```

and invoke it using `d()`. It will shorten the syntax, but you will have to always travel one level up in the call stack to get to the code that you are actually trying to debug.

[image: DevTools Call Stack]

In my opinion you should simply set up a snippet (or a "live template") in your editor/IDE that will replace key combination `d + TAB` with `debugger;`.

- [Snippets in Sublime](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/extensibility/snippets.html)
- [Live templates in WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/creating-and-editing-live-templates.html)
- [Code templates in NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/code-templates.html#define)

Comment: +1 for snippets suggestion. If you regularly use multiple editors as I do, I would suggest using a text expansion tool; then you can write your snippets once and use them everywhere.